# AngularJS - How to keep original value if I don't hit submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of users on the left with the details on the right. 
The right details are handled with a form, and inputs with ng-model. So when I click on a user on the left, I change the selected user and the model automatically shows me the proper details on the right.

I also have a submit button that saves changes to the server.

This all works well, but the problem is that if I change a user's name for example, click on another user, and then come back to the first user, I see the changed name, but the info was never saved on the server. So the client might think that the info was changed on the server, when it wasn't. After I hit refresh, I get the old, server values back.

So how can I revert model changes if I switch the model before hitting save?

By the way, I'm using `ng-model` instead of using `{{ }}` in the value field, because AngularJS validators don't work unless you use ng-model

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show us your code.

Comment: the form collection has a `$setPristine()` function.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setPristine.  However, this really depends on how you are changing the model.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Claies, I upvoted as I didn't know about that and it sounds very useful for another use case, although it didn't work my current scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime user selects the item in the left, copy that selected object into new variable. You can copy using angular.copy function. Then show that new variable on the right side in the form. Right now changes are "saved" because you are referencing items in your array (so when you change something in form it is changed into this item in array). If you have new variable for selectedItem you won't have this problem any more.

Comment: thank you for the angular.copy mention, that's what I ended up using and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest binding an object to the input fields of your form and using ng-submit to call a function to update your values on the server, much like Nemanja suggested.

I went ahead and made a simple [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martellaj/8Lqatqbp/) so you have a small example to structure your code around. Hope it helps!

HTML:

```
<form ng-model="data" ng-submit="simple.saveName()">
  Name: {{ simple.data.name }}
  <br />Twitter: {{ simple.data.twitter }}
  <br />
  <br />New name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="simple.newName" />
  <br />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('app', [])
        .controller('simpleController', SimpleController);

    function SimpleController() {
        var vm = this;

        // Public stuff.
        vm.data = {
            name: 'Joe',
            twitter: '@martellaj'
        };
        vm.newName;
        vm.saveName = saveName;

        // Private stuff.
        function saveName() {
            console.log('Saving name...');
            vm.data.name = vm.newName;
        };
    };
})();
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, I upvoted your answer for its usefulness although I chose Nemanja's answer because he mentioned the angular.copy function which is what I ended up using.

Comment: No problem. I read up on angular.copy() myself and got to learn a little something new!